# Is it possible to use wine to run window games that is already installed on a external hard drive (and to install future software on the external)?

Tags: windows, wine, games, external-hdd

I would like to know if it is possible to run Windows games that are already installed on an external hard drive and have it load up though wine?  Or do the games need to be installed by wine first before i can play them?

And also i like to know how to tell wine to install any future Windows software that does work on wine to install them on a different drive than hard drive inside my computer?

and if the answer to the first question is the 2nd one. what will happen to the one already on the hard drive if i manage to get wine to install it there?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on game. Most modern games require proper installation in the registry so it would be better to first install the game through Wine.

But if you know what keys game uses, you can easily import them inside Wine registry. It is simple ini-like text file `$WINEPREFIX/system.reg` and `$WINEPREFIX/user.reg`.

To use multiple drives, you have to tell Wine where are they located. This can be done in Wine configuration. Run `winecfg` and select *Drives* tab:

[image]

There, you can manage your drives.